# Json Value in SQL Server when we have a list

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data in SQL Server like this:

| ID | Json_Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Book_id":"6842","index":1,"type":"BOOK"},{"Book_id":"103735","index":2,"type":"BOOK"}, {"Book_id":"104253","index":3,"type":"BOOK_GIFT"}, {"Book_id":"83886","index":4,"type":"BOOK"}] |
| 2 | [{"Book_id":"688","index":1,"type":"BOOK"},{"Book_id":"548","index":2,"type":"BOOK"}] |

I need to parse this data to get something like this :

| id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Book_id":"6842","index":1,"type":"BOOK"} | {"Book_id":"103735","index":2,"type":"BOOK"} | {"Book_id":"104253","index":3,"type":"BOOK_GIFT"} | {"Book_id":"83886","index":4,"type":"BOOK"} |
| 2 | {"Book_id":"688","index":1,"type":"BOOK"} | {"Book_id":"548","index":2,"type":"BOOK"} | Null | Null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use:

```
SELECT value
FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(Json_Data, '$')
```

to get a row-based output - or if you can be sure you never have more than 4 entries, you could also use this:

```
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(Json_Data, '$[0]'),
    JSON_QUERY(Json_Data, '$[1]'),
    JSON_QUERY(Json_Data, '$[2]'),
    JSON_QUERY(Json_Data, '$[3]')
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
```